# turning Sqlite records into python variables

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.10, pyqt6

This is my code. The code in `email_compare()` is my problem. I want it to take the input from the email box and compare it to the emails in my Sqlite database using a linear search. The problem is that though the input is exactly the same it won't output that it is correct. I have had to delete certain parts of my code due to having more code than writing so if it is required I will right back to say what I have deleted. Also I am not sure if you can turn Sqlite records into variables that can actually be compared so if there is another way of doing this then I would greatly appreciate being told how to do it in that method instead of what I am trying to do now.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3
from SIGNUP import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    
    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        Dialog.close()
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(480, 620)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(64, 64, 64)")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 60, 200, 50))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font-size: 28pt;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 150, 91, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 23pt; color: rgb(255, 0, 0)")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        
        self.email = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.email.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 190, 251, 41))
        self.email.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.email.setObjectName("email")
        
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 260, 101, 41))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 23pt; color: rgb(255, 0, 0)")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 300, 251, 41))
        self.password.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.password.setText("")
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        
        self.loginbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.loginbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 390, 100, 32))
        self.loginbutton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0)")
        self.loginbutton.setObjectName("loginbutton")
        
        self.loginbutton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.loginbutton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 390, 100, 32))
        self.loginbutton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 212);")
        self.loginbutton_2.setObjectName("loginbutton_2")

        self.loginbutton_2.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)

        self.loginbutton.clicked.connect(self.show_password)
        self.loginbutton.clicked.connect(self.email_compare)
        
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Email"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Password"))
        self.loginbutton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login!"))
        self.loginbutton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Sign up!"))


    # this is my problem
    def email_compare(self):
        count = 0
        check = self.email.text()
        check = "('"+check+"',)"
        conn = sqlite3.connect("U+P.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT email FROM Details")
        compare = c.fetchall() 
        print(compare)
        print(check)
        right = False
        while count < len(compare) and right == False:
            print(compare[count])
            if compare[count] == check:
                print("Correct email")
                right = True
            else:
                count = count + 1
        conn.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You could do `c.execute("""SELECT email FROM Details where email = ?""", (check,))` which will return the row(s) matching `check` if it exists.  Then just check whether `c.fetchall()` empty or not.

Comment: To retrieve both if email matches: `c.execute("""SELECT email, password FROM Details where email = ?""", (check,))` or to test both email and password match `c.execute("""SELECT email, password FROM Details where email = ? AND password = ?""", (check, the_password))`